# Window scrolling and offest not working in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I'm working on a simple 2d tile based game in Python using Pygame. I've got the basics of a camera starting to work, it is bliting the tiles at an offset but the actual rects of the tiles aren't moving with the blitting. Here's the camera class, really simple :

```
from Map import level
import Globals as gb
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, screen_width, screen_height):
        self.rect = gb.pygame.Rect(x, y, screen_width, screen_height)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = gb.player.rect.x, gb.player.rect.y
```

and the blitting is done here as so:

```
def render(fov, cam):
    for block in new_blocks:
        gb.window.screen.blit(block.image, (block.rect.x - cam.rect.x,
        block.rect.y - cam.rect.y))
```

the map is a simple 2d array, and I'm putting all the tiles into the list "new_blocks"
like this:

```
for row in level.current_map:
    for block in row:
        if block == '.':
            block = Blocks()
            block.pic = 'sand.png'
            block.rect.x = x
            block.rect.y = y
            x += 50
            new_blocks.append(block)
        if block == '#':
            block = Blocks()
            block.ID = 1
            block.is_wall = True
            newImage(block, 'img', 'wall.png')
            block.rect.x = x
            block.rect.y = y
            walls.append(block)
            x += 50
            new_blocks.append(block)
        if x == len(level.current_map[0])*50:
            y += 50
            x = 0
```

A lot of this is messy, and I'm planning to clean it up and use more constants and declare better variables after I get this working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're asking. Are you saying that the tiles are being blitted in the correct spot, but the actual tile.x and tile.y are not changing?

Comment: Yes! The tiles are shown in the correct place, but it gives "ghost" rects that the player is colliding with.

Comment: Are you sure you are moving and colliding the player based on the absolute positions. You arent affecting the position of the block rects, so provided you move the character absolutely then convert to camera all should be fine. A bit more code please if that's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing: You don't want the camera to modify the actual coordinate values of the tiles themselves. The answer is actually quite simple, when you blit the character, use the camera to modify where the character is being blitted. Then for everything you draw to the screen, there will be two different sets of coordinates. 1) The actual position of the object and 2) The coordinates relative to the screen. The one thing you need to watch out for is that every single object is drawn relative to the screen, because if just one of them is not, it will mess up your collision detection.